# Any possibility to use ZFS for Samba4 AD DC share on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: samba, samba4, ubuntu-16.04, btrfs, zfsonlinux

For a few (~ 5) PCs running Windows 8.1 I have to setup a domain controller using Samba4 on Ubuntu 16.04 Server. 
Additionally the DC should provide a few shared folders with user-specific access and act as a printer server.

To prevent data corruption I thought about using ZFS in mirror mode to store the share folders' contents, but looking at the possible values for the ZOL parameter "acltype" I get the impression that ZFS on Linux only implements POSIX ACLs.

This in turn would render my plan impossible because according to [1] a Samba4 AD DC needs NFS ACLs and I have no other machine available to use as a Samba File server (where this restriction does not exist).

Is there anything I could do to use ZFS nonetheless or do I have to use a different file system, e.g. Btrfs (of which I don't know if it is mature enough for production use)?

Thanks in advance.

[1] https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller#Using_the_Domain_Controller_as_a_File_Server

EDIT @zoredache:
I already thought about doing it this way but I don't know if there could be a problem if the DC is available only after the NAS has completed its boot process. And to be honest ZFS was appealing due to all its features but I don't think it is really necessary. Just wanted to prevent bit rot but I am sure there are alternatives...

@ewwhite
Unfortunately Windows Server is not an option due to the costs - I am setting this thing up for a small charity organization.

Comment: Man, I'd just use Windows. There's way too much to go awry with this based on what you've described.

Comment: Any chance you could setup the 'server' as a hypervisor, and run your DC in one VM, and your file servers in another VM?  Perhaps using ZFS on the hypervisor OS?

Comment: @Apollo13 Did you ever manage to solve this? I'm trying to do the same thing, and I'm left with the same questions regarding ACLs.

Comment: @Onno No, sorry. Apparently there is just no possibility to enable the needed features or to circumvent the need ...